# Find all the keywords of java language and the names of the java API classes

Tags: java

I want to ask you a question.I am not sure I will get any answers but I will give it try:)

As the header says, I need a way(e.g a file from sun's website) that contains all the keywords of the java language and also the class names of the java API.I know that there is some way, as the compiler has this list on his disposal but I don't know how to get it.

Any ideas?Thanks on advance.

P.S:Feel free to edit the tags, I dont know what else to add.

Comment: It isn't homeworks:-)

I just want to figure out some things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java keywords](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). [Core Java classes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html) (names in italics are interfaces). [Even more classes](http://java.sun.com/javase/reference/api.jsp).

Comment: There are of course quite some classes in packages that are not in that list. `com.sun...` comes to mind.

Comment: That's because those are not part of the core API.

Answer (score 3):

The keywords: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

And each version of Java will have some different classes. Newer versions will probably have more classes. And in future releases it is possible that deprecated classes will be left out, although that is not very likely to happen quickly because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Can you elaborate "the class names will probably differ from platform to platform"?

Comment: At least javax.* packages do vary as do cryptography related stuff due to dumb laws in some countries.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: I was thinking about OS specific stuff. But Zed correctly mentioned the fact that these classes are not part of the public API, so I will edit my answer.

Comment: Nice...dynamic refreshing of the list is a problem but not critical.At the moment I am ok.